# Looking for Hash function supported in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hash

I am looking for `hash function`, that I can use in `Postgresql` to be more specific in `Amazon Aurora Db`. The `Hash` value generated should be of 8 bytes long that can be stored in `string` field of length 8.

Do we have any such `hash function` that matches the above mentioned criteria. Any leads on this would be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store 8 bytes as 8 characters. But a `bytea` would work; for example

```
SELECT ('\x' || to_hex(hashtextextended('dsadswa', 0)))::bytea;

       bytea        
════════════════════
 \x14862f5b0ca6bca6
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz. Could you please help me in understating the answer. Let me write here what I understood.
First, you are doing `hashtextextended`. Then converting it to `hex` by `to_hex`.
The `||` for concat, I think ? If yes, why it is required?
What is the use of  `bytea`. Could you please explain.

Comment: `bytea` is the PostgreSQL data type for binary strings. I convert that hex value into the string representation of a `bytea` (for example, `'\xdeadbeef'`) and perform a type cast to `bytea`.